# Laravel Nova Dashboard Not loading

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-nova

I have recently licensed Laravel Nova. But I am failed to see the dashboard.

I have installed fresh laravel project and followed all the instructions provided at [installation link](https://nova.laravel.com/docs/1.0/installation.html#installing-nova).

Every thing goes fine. But still, I am unable to view the nova dashboard. Find enclosed herewith my directory structure, composer, .env and a screenshot of the database. Kindly guide/resolve, please.

When I am trying to laod dashboard (http://localhost/fgfast/nova/) It displayed my directory structure instead of dashboard.

[image]

Comment: Do not post a picture of your code, paste your code with your question.

Comment: "But still I am unable to view nova dashboard." What does this mean exactly? You see a white screen? You see an error? If so what is the error?

Comment: Actulay css is not loaded correctly. Simple (without css and js) login screen appears.